# Background-color isn't working on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with background color of my select (with chosen)...

[image]

I tried to use background-color and background properties to change the color of the select on IE, like this:

```
.select-footer .chzn-container-single .chzn-single, .select-footer .chzn-container .chzn-drop {
  background-color: #333948;
}

.select-footer .chzn-container-single .chzn-single, .select-footer .chzn-container .chzn-drop {
  background: #333948;
}
```

The version are CSS 3 and Internet Explorer 9+.
Anyone have an idea of what's going on with IE? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Version could be usefull?

Comment: CSS 3 and Internet Explorer 9

Comment: Can you upload the image?

Comment: And please upload the HTML as well, or try to recreate your issue in a fiddle.

Comment: My html is a basic select tag with options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missing an `!important` here:

```
.chzn-container-single .chzn-single{
  background-color: #333948 !important;
}
```

Chosen does copy the select-tag and implement an own element that simulates the select functionality. You can see this behavior in your DOM inspector. 
So if you add an own class-attribute to the select-tag, it normally gets ignored. You can work around this issue by using the adjacent sibling selector:

```
.myCssClass + .chzn-container-single .chzn-single{
  background-color: #333948 !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried the !important, but is still not working.. I hate IE >.< !!

Comment: tried it here. Works perfectly. Try to remove your `.select-footer` to see if this is causing the error.

Comment: I tried to remove .select-footer too. Still the same problem. I think the problem isn't with subscribing classes..

Comment: and also set : `background-image:none !important;` and `background:none !important;`! By the way, you are using an old version of chosen. The css-prefix has changed to `chosen` instead of `chzn`

Comment: Man, thank you very much. I tried this steps, and still not working... ='[

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem setting the filter property to none. This filter was applied by the CSS of chosen.

Answer (score -1):

You can test the IE version that you have with a simple testpage containing one div and the attributes that you want to apply, but both this css properties are supported by IE >4 version so better check the inheritance of classes that you have on your page